# Print multiple fields based on partial substring match inside one of the fields

Tags: text-processing

From this data:

```
"STRING1","c45621396a774a7a79b095a1b73b1d3b","2016-04-14T19:39:41.529978","1.0.4.4","7-sp1.0-amd64","","10.224.241.219|0.0.0.0|0.0.0.0|192.168.0.6|0.0.0.0"
"STRING2","c5815139f3051de2ab67909b03a01203","2016-04-14T19:37:47.991569","1.0.4.4","7-sp1.0-amd64","","10.230.16.188"
"STRING3","c837513923e2abfe4df41c2240d1c869","2016-04-14T19:40:10.385759","1.0.4.4","7-sp1.0-amd64","","0.0.0.0|0.0.0.0|0.0.0.0|10.226.41.43"
"STRING4","c837544923e2abfe4df41c2240d1c869","2016-04-14T19:40:10.385779","1.0.4.4","7-sp0.0-amd64","","8.8.8.8|0.0.0.0|0.0.0.0|0.0.0.0|10.226.41.43"
"STRING5","c837544003e2abfe4df41c2240d1c869","2016-04-14T19:40:10.382379","1.0.4.4","7-sp0.0-amd64","","0.0.0.0|10.20.40.6|0.0.0.0|10.226.41.43"
```

I wish to keep only

- the first field (which is a string with unpredictable alphanum/length) and
- from the sixth field, only IP addresses (there may be one or more) beginning with 10.

Based on the sample below, here's the desired output:

```
STRING1 10.224.241.219
STRING2 10.230.16.188
STRING3 10.226.41.43
STRING4 10.226.41.43
STRING5 10.20.40.6 10.226.41.43
```

What's the sed/awk magic that can achieve this? I can use any standard text processing utils on a GNU/Linux system or cygwin to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: `cut -d , -f 1,6 < your_file | fgrep ',"10.'`

Comment: Yes. Do you want the first field to always be printed and the 6th only if it begins with 10? Or do you want to print the 1st and 6th fields of only those lines whose 6th field begins with a 10? Also, can you have commas inside your fields? Something like `"foo,bar"` is valid csv format, can your data have that sort of thing?

Comment: @terdon thank you I added the missing ",". Perhaps `fgrep` is deprecated as `man` or `nslookup` were before :) .

Comment: @Emmanuel see `man fgrep`. Also see the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) for `grep`: "This grep has been enhanced in an upwards-compatible way to provide the exact functionality of the historical egrep and fgrep commands as well. It was the clear intention of the standard developers to consolidate the three greps into a single command." While `fgrep` is currently and is likely to be supported for a while, it is a good idea to get into the habit of using `grep -F` instead since `fgrep` will probably disappear eventually.

Comment: @terdon Yes I read it too, you are right in every aspects. I think I will still  use `fgrep`  on command line as an alternative to `grep -F` but not in scripts. I think also that  `fgrep` will last long, yet it  is implemented as a script wrapper of `grep` and the cost is minimal. Final command is  
`cut -d , -f 1,6 < your_file | grep  ',"10\.'`

Comment: Note that **this cannot be considered as an answer**, It is depending on how the raw data are formatted. it is not specifically checking the IP field.

Comment: @terdon No commas inside fields. I want the first field to always be printed, and only the 10.x.x.x IP address from the sixth field. The 10.x.x.x will not necessarily be the first IP to be noted in the 6th field - as shown in the sample  data.

Comment: @wmln OK, then please [edit] your question as requested and show us your desired output. I saw that the `10.x.x.x` IP is not always the first, but had no way of knowing whether you want such lines or not. Whenever you ask a `text-processing` question, you must always include both an example input and the output you want to see from that input. Also tell us what operating system you are using since the tools available to you (and the details of their implementations) will depend on it.

Comment: Oh, and can you have more than one matching IP on the same line? If so, please [edit] your question to include an example showing that.

Comment: Do you have `perl`?

Comment: @terdon - Yes, I do, updated the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your fields never contain commas, you could try:

```
$ perl -F, -lane '@k=split(/["|]/,$F[6]); 
                  @l=grep{/^10\./}@k; 
                  print "$F[0] @l"' file | 
    sed 's/"//g'
STRING1 10.224.241.219
STRING2 10.230.16.188
STRING3 10.226.41.43
STRING4 10.226.41.43
STRING5 10.20.40.6 10.226.41.43
```

#### Explanation

Perl's `-a` option makes it work like `awk`, it will split its input files on the value given by `-F` and save each resulting field as an element in the array `@F`. So, the 1st field will be `$F[0]`, the 2nd `$F[1]` etc. The `-l` option adds a newline to each `print` call and the `-n` tells `perl` to read its input file line by line and apply the script given by `-e` to each line.

- `@k=split(/["|]/,$F[6]);` : split the 7th field on `"` or `|` and save it as the array `@k`. This will be the IPs.
- `@l=grep{/^10\./}@k;` : save all fields from `@k` that start with a `10` in the array `@l`.
- `print "$F[0] @l"` : print the 1st field and whatever is in `@l`.
- `sed 's/"//g'` : remove quotes. Since `perl` will split the input lines before running anything else, it is easier to use another program for this.

You could also shorten the Perl script by not using temporary array variables:

```
perl -F, -lane 'print "$F[0] ", join " ", grep{/^10\..*/} split(/["|]/,$F[6])' file
```

Comment: thank you, I had to modify this to perl -F, -lane 'print "$F[1] ", grep{/^10\..*/} split(/["|]/,$F[6])' file to get it to print the first STRING and the matched IP addresses. I'm using perl v5.18.2.

Comment: @wmln you're welcome. And that's odd. The `$F[1]` is the second comma-defined field. That should print the hash sum (or whatever that is) not the string. Anyway, glad you got it to work.

Comment: Apologies - I just noticed a small bug - IP results are not delimited - making further processing cumbersome. So my results look like 10.x.x.x10.y.y.y - Can this be changed to use comma as the output delimiter - including in between IP results?

Comment: @wmln they're separated by spaces in the output. If you want commas, you could always pass the whole thing through another sed: `sed 's/ /,/g'`

Comment: Not sure why, but my output is not space separated. It looks like this: STRING1 10.x.x.x10.y.y.y - there is only one space, between the string and the IPs.

Comment: The full version of the perl command works as expected, with spaces in between IPs. The shortened version of the perl command seems to have this bug.

Comment: @wmln ah, yes indeed. My bad, sorry, see updated answer.

Comment: minor variation of @terdon's answer, preserves the original input format exactly:  `perl -F, -lane '@k = split(/["|]/, $F[6]); 
                @l = grep{/^10\./} @k; 
                print join(",", $F[0], "\"" . join("|",@l) . "\"")' wmin.txt`